# NSURLConnection JSON Submit to Server

Tags: ios, ruby, json, nsurlconnection

I am at a loss here, I thought I'd try something new with web services for my app.

I can pull data down no problem, but I am trying to post to the server and just can seem to get this to even fire.

What I am intending to happen is on submit button press the action be fired:

```
- (IBAction)didPressSubmit:(id)sender {

     //JSON SERIALIZATION OF DATA
     NSMutableDictionary *projectDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectName text] forKey:@"name"];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectDescShort text] forKey:@"desc_short"];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectDescLong text] forKey:@"desc_long"];

    NSError *jsonSerializationError = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:projectDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonSerializationError];

    if(!jsonSerializationError) {
        NSString *serJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Serialized JSON: %@", serJSON);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"JSON Encoding Failed: %@", [jsonSerializationError localizedDescription]);
    }

    // JSON POST TO SERVER
    NSURL *projectsUrl = [NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://70.75.66.136:3000/projects.json"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *dataSubmit = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:projectsUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [dataSubmit setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; // 1
    [dataSubmit setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"]; // 2
    [dataSubmit setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; // 3
    [dataSubmit setHTTPBody: jsonData];

     [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:dataSubmit delegate:self];
}
```

After that it runs through:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"DidReceiveResponse");

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    NSLog(@"DidReceiveData");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"BLAH CHECK YOUR NETWORK" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

I am obviously missing something, but I don't even know where to look. All I need is a point in the right direction, any help would be great.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the request to fire with the following.

Okay I was able to get the request to fire using the following:

```
- (IBAction)didPressSubmit:(id)sender {


    NSMutableDictionary *projectDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectName text] forKey:@"name"];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectDescShort text] forKey:@"desc_small"];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectDescLong text] forKey:@"desc_long"];

    NSError *jsonSerializationError = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:projectDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonSerializationError];

    if(!jsonSerializationError) {
        NSString *serJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Serialized JSON: %@", serJSON);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"JSON Encoding Failed: %@", [jsonSerializationError localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSURL *projectsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://70.75.66.136:3000/projects.json"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:projectsUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; // 1
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"]; // 2
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; // 3
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData]; // 4


    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}
```

But for some reason the post method only received a bunch of nil values, I am getting this from the server side. `Processing by ProjectsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"{\n  \"desc_long\" : \"a\",\n  \"name\" : \"a\",\n  \"desc_small\" : \"a\"\n}"=>nil}`

**UPDATE 2**

With a little read from here: http://elusiveapps.com/blog/2011/04/ios-json-post-to-ruby-on-rails/

I was able to see if missed the following line.
`[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

So final didPressSubmit code is as follows;

```
- (IBAction)didPressSubmit:(id)sender {


    NSMutableDictionary *projectDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectName text] forKey:@"name"];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectDescShort text] forKey:@"desc_small"];
    [projectDictionary setObject:[projectDescLong text] forKey:@"desc_long"];

    NSError *jsonSerializationError = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:projectDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonSerializationError];

    if(!jsonSerializationError) {
        NSString *serJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Serialized JSON: %@", serJSON);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"JSON Encoding Failed: %@", [jsonSerializationError localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSURL *projectsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://70.75.66.136:3000/projects.json"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:projectsUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; // 1
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"]; // 2
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; // 3
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData]; // 4


    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}
```

Comment: What is happening here:  `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:dataSubmit delegate:self];`?  You aren't assigning the newly initialized connection to a variable.

Comment: Try using NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: method.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue but I resolved it by setting the options to nil.

Replace

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:projectDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonSerializationError];
```

by

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:projectDictionary options:nil error:&jsonSerializationError];
```

Use option to `nil` if you are sending json to server, if you are displaying json use `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`.

Hope this will help you.